# swift 3 and UIImageview case

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, uiimageview, xcode8

I have two objects the first one is ImageView and the second one is TextView.

I did animation for these objects. If the user click on the image the textView expand to show the whole text. However, when the textView expands, the imageView displays weird size of the image. it looks like super zoom In.

[This picture to make it clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6TAS.jpg)

and here's my code

```
import UIKit
```

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

```
var imageViewArray = [UIImage]()
var textArray = [String]()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    imageViewArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "a"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "b"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "c")]


    textArray = [
        // firststory Starts
        "firststory",

                 // SecondStory starts
                 "Hello",

                 // thirdStors starts
                 "thirdStory"]

}




override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageViewArray.count

}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

    // give the objects their IDs

    let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    imageView.image = imageViewArray[indexPath.row]


    let textView = cell.viewWithTag(2)  as! UITextView
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.text = textArray[indexPath.row]




    let backButton = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton
    backButton.isHidden = true



    return cell
}


// adding some animation to the cells

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

    cell?.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: cell!)



    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: [], animations: ({



        cell?.frame = collectionView.bounds
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false

        let textView = cell!.viewWithTag(2)  as! UITextView
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false


        // some codes to help back button to work !
        let backButton = cell!.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton
        backButton.isHidden = false
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CollectionViewController.backbtnAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)



    }), completion: nil)



}


// back button

func backbtnAction() {

    let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems
    collectionView?.isScrollEnabled = true
    collectionView?.reloadItems(at: indexPath!)
}
```

}

Comment: What is your question? It's not clear what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ImageView content mode is set to .scaleAspectFit or .scaleAspectFill